# Persisting Session of Tomcat Server Application between re deploymets from Myeclipse IDE

Tags: java, tomcat, myeclipse

All
I am developing an web application using Tomcat 6.X and My Eclipse.
When i do some changes in existing java files (Java Class, SERVLETS , Filter) , i have to redeploy it to the tomcat server . but, when i redeploy the application the

> existing session becomes null .

is there any way that i can persist the existing session between re deployments from the MY ECLISPE.

Answer (score 2):

From [Tomcat Docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/config/manager.html)

Check here for tutorial on [JDBC persistence](http://www.jajakarta.org/tomcat/tomcat3.2-4.0/tomcat-4.0b5/src/catalina/docs/JDBCStore-howto.html) , [tomcat-6-session-persistence-through-jdbcstore](http://tomcat-6-session-persistence-through-jdbcstore)

- FileBased
- JDBC Based Store

> **Restart Persistence**
>
> Whenver Catalina is shut down normally and restarted, or when an
>   application reload is triggered, the
>   standard Manager implementation will
>   attempt to serialize all currently
>   active sessions to a disk file located
>   via the pathname attribute. All such
>   saved sessions will then be
>   deserialized and activated (assuming
>   they have not expired in the mean
>   time) when the application reload is
>   completed.
>
> In order to successfully restore the state of session attributes, all
>   such attributes MUST implement the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. You
>   MAY cause the Manager to enforce this
>   restriction by including the
>    element in your web
>   application deployment descriptor
>   (/WEB-INF/web.xml).